# Is there a support methodology for UAT?

Tags: user-acceptance-testing

For quality assurance engineeres supporting the UAT phase of the customer, is there any defined methodology to track support issues, communicate, define roles and responsibilities while communicating?

Comment: I'm 100% sure this was intended for the main site, not for the meta site. My concern is whether to migrate it there, or whether or not this is a fleshed out enough question to migrate.

Comment: Yes, it is. Should it be migrated?

Comment: I'll migrate it. I don't know enough about UAT methodologies to know what questions to ask, but I suspect those with more expertise than I will have followup questions to get you to expand this question to make it more answerable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined methodology for UAT support as such. However you can follow what we do. We are an Agile Team following Scrum. One iteration is dedicated to UAT support and we have a different test strategy for UAT support defining the roles, responsibilities, risk mitigation and escalation path. We do have QA on call support for 24*7 for these two weeks and the client is billed accordingly. 
In UAT support we support them with configurations, data setup and other issues. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Sure,
There is always a support methodology for everything, even for UAT. The only problem is that it is always context dependent. There is no one size fits all rule for such a thing. You have to identify the needs and requirements and develop a support methodology for UAT depending on the context of the SUT(system/software under test). For this you can take help from various stakeholders, specially the user/client, since they are the one's for whom you will be doing User Acceptance Test - UAT.

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute defined methodology to track issues, communicate, etc. But you can see some samples that suit for your needs.

As examples:

1. Issue Tracking: The very simple is by creating on a spreadsheet, just list one by one what's you need, and then review, review, and review again, until you satisfied. You can also ask someone who understand about what will be checks whether by technical or functionality.
2. Communication: I think your requirement is related between "Communicate" and "Define roles and responsibilities while communicating". So, just create a communication plan, put all needed roles, available PIC (can be person, division, etc). Then draw a flow that describe when there is an issue come so what they should do what you should do? You may put some hint such as balloon to describe a responsibilities and step number. Same as an issue tracking, just review, review, and review again (just manage your time to design, create, and review). It is good to draw on presentation form rather than a spreadsheet form.